# Modeling nested documents with Spring-Data-MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

I have a MongoDB database that represents snippets of public gene information like so:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    symbol: "GENEA",
    db_references: {
        "DB A": "DBA000123",
        "DB B" ["ABC123", "DEF456"]
    }
}
```

I am trying to map this to a `@Document`-annotated POJO class, like this:

```
@Document
Public class Gene {
    @Id 
    private int id;
    private String symbol;
    private Map<String,Object> db_references;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Because of the nature of MongoDB's schema-less design, the `db_references` field can contain a long list of possible keys, with values sometimes being arrays or other key-value pairs.  My primary concern is the speed at which I can fetch multiple `Gene` documents and slice up their `db_references`.

My question: what is the best way to represent this field to optimize fetching performance?  Should I define a custom POJO and map this field to it?  Should I make it a `BasicDBObject`?  Or would it be best not map the documents at all with Spring Data and just use the MongoDB Java driver and parse the DBObjects returned?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this qn?

Comment: @arun: No, I never found an adequate answer to this question.

Comment: For my problem, I have decided to go with the last approach you mention: `just use the MongoDB Java driver and parse the DBObjects returned`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to see your question hasn't been answered yet.

If db_references represent an actual concept within the domain you are much better off capturing this domain knowledge in a class. It is always a good idea and MongoDB helps with it a lot.

Thus, you can store this list of nested objects inside the MongoDB document and fetch the whole aggregate in a single query. Spring Data should also handle deserializing as well.

Comment: Could you provide an example?